# apt не видит сеть, хотя интернет есть

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, dns, apt-get

apt и его производные напрочь отказываются видеть ip адреса. DNS стоит как в системе так и на роутере от Google. Через браузер эти же сервера открываются и пингуются через ping. Proxy отсутствует.
Тип системы Kde Neon(Ubuntu 16.04).
Версия apt 1.2.20.
Команду запускаю так: `sudo aptitude update`, но и с любой другой apt-подобной прогой так же.
Вывод ping:

```
PING www.google.com (74.125.232.241) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 74.125.232.241: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=8.73 ms
```

Dig не установлен и установить не смогу по понятным причинам.

```
Ошк:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
  Could not resolve host: repo.skype.com
Ошк:2 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve host: apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
Ошк:3 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
  Could not resolve host: storage.googleapis.com
Ошк:4 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve host: apt.dockerproject.org
Ошк:5 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
  Could not resolve host: packagecloud.io
Ошк:6 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «repo.vivaldi.com»
Ошк:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Ошк:8 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ru.archive.ubuntu.com»
Ошк:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/qdirstat/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Ошк:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ru.archive.ubuntu.com»
Ошк:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Ошк:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «archive.canonical.com»
Ошк:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Ошк:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «security.ubuntu.com»
Ошк:15 http://apt.llvm.org/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «apt.llvm.org»
Ошк:16 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «download.mono-project.com»
Ошк:17 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/lts xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «archive.neon.kde.org»
Ошк:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Ошк:19 http://apt.llvm.org/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-4.0 InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «apt.llvm.org»
Ошк:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Ошк:21 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ru.archive.ubuntu.com»
Ошк:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Ошк:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «ppa.launchpad.net»
Сущ:24 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease
Чтение списков пакетов…
Построение дерева зависимостей…
Чтение информации о состоянии…
Все пакеты имеют последние версии.
```

Comment: тип системы, версия apt, как запускаете комаду, ping www.google.com, dig www.google.com - добавте в вопрос, легче будетинайти решение

Comment: ...и классическое – перезагружались ли.

Comment: Добавил дополнительной информации.

Comment: `sudo ping repo.skype.com` работает?

Comment: Есть вариант, что в apt настроен прокси

Comment: repo.skype.com пинугется

Comment: а если сделать `sudo apt -y upgrade`?

Comment: @Wanket: именно через `sudo` работает или вы просто `ping` сделали?

Comment: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy` там есть строчки про прокси?

Comment: apt.conf: Debug::pkgProblemResolver "true";
Acquire::Languages "none"; Proxy файлов нет

Comment: У вас проблемы с DNS. Там могут быть разные варианты. Для начала можно попробовать `echo nameserver 8.8.4.4 > /etc/resolv.conf`.